# About kamathanha during vipassana

Tags: theravada

When kamathanha disappears  during meditation ?is it during sotapanna state or sakadagami state?

Answer (score 1):

Kamathanha is subdued(temporarily) when you attain any Jhana(Dyana). Kamathanha is weakened(permanently) when you attain Sakadagami. Kamathanha is eradicated(permanently) when you attain Anagami.

Comment: In jhana whether only thoughts will disappear or both thoughts and changes of body will disappear?

Comment: In Jhana the mind attains one pointedness.